# caret package confusion matrix define positive case with multiple classes

Tags: r, classification, r-caret

from the docs of caret::confusionMatrix:

```
positive: an optional character string for the factor level that
corresponds to a "positive" result (if that makes sense for your
data). If there are only two factor levels, the first level will
be used as the "positive" result.
```

This sounds like it would be possible to define a positive case in a multiclass problem and hence get a classic binary confusion matrix with positive (defined class) vs negative (all the other classes). However, when using the positive attribute on multiclass data, it doesn't change the output of confusionMatrix.

```
# generate fake data
data = data.frame(measured=as.factor(rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), c(30,40,30))),
    modeled=as.factor(rep(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A'), c(30,10,20,40))))

# get confusion matrix
matrix = caret::confusionMatrix(data$modeled, dat$measured, positive='A')
```

gives

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  A  B  C
         A 30 10 30
         B  0 10  0
         C  0 20  0

Overall Statistics

               Accuracy : 0.4             
                 95% CI : (0.3033, 0.5028)
    No Information Rate : 0.4             
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.5379          

                  Kappa : 0.1304          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 5.878e-13       

Statistics by Class:

                     Class: A Class: B Class: C
Sensitivity            1.0000   0.2500   0.0000
Specificity            0.4286   1.0000   0.7143
Pos Pred Value         0.4286   1.0000   0.0000
Neg Pred Value         1.0000   0.6667   0.6250
Prevalence             0.3000   0.4000   0.3000
Detection Rate         0.3000   0.1000   0.0000
Detection Prevalence   0.7000   0.1000   0.2000
Balanced Accuracy      0.7143   0.6250   0.3571
```

Did I simply misinterpret the docs or is there really a way to get the binary matrix?
I know, that I can produce the desired output myself but if there is a chance to be lazy, I will take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a misinterpretation. It happens that `positive` is not used anywhere when there are more than two classes. First `caret:::confusionMatrix.default` gets called for some "formalities" and then we go to `caret:::confusionMatrix.table`. There `positive` gets used multiple times when there are two classes, but nothing outside of that `if` case.

As you said, it's not hard to achieve that by hand. For a quick glance you may use simply

```
table(data.frame(data == "A"))
#         modeled
# measured FALSE TRUE
#    FALSE    30   40
#    TRUE      0   30
```

where `A` and `TRUE` correspond to the positive class and `FALSE` to everything else.